# Images not scaling

Tags: css, image, responsive, scaling

There are 3 images on my [homepage](http://www.whitehallpubliclibrary.org) that I want to make responsive. They are not scaling. I have removed any reference to height or width size in the html.  I tried to use the `CSS` rule max-width that targets the image as a percentage relative width value, but can't get it to work.

My html looks like this:

```
<div class ="wrapper2">
    <div>
        <a href="https://www.whitehallpubliclibrary.org/kids-parent/kids/special-events-for-kids/"><img src="https://www.whitehallpubliclibrary.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/kidsspecialevents.jpg" /></a></div>
<div>
        <a href="https://www.whitehallpubliclibrary.org/teens-parent/teens/special-events-for-teens/"><img src="https://www.whitehallpubliclibrary.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/teenspecialevents.jpg" /></a></div>
    <div>
        <a href="https://www.whitehallpubliclibrary.org/adults-parent/adults/special-events-for-adults/"><img src="https://www.whitehallpubliclibrary.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/adultspecialevents.jpg" /></a></div>
    </div>
```

The css (that doesn't work) looks like this:

`.wrapper img {max-width:100%;}`

Any help with this would be appreciated. I've been working on and off with it for months! Thank you

Comment: All that does is say, "I don't want the image to be any larger than 100%". It does not scale the image in any way. Note: the `<img>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Like Rob said, the `.wrapper img {max-width:100%;}` only tells the browser you don't want the image to be wider the 100% of the browser window's width.

Check out this code pen with your supplied HTML that shows want you'd like: [Code Pen](https://codepen.io/kalervohyyppa/pen/ZEGEQjG)

The width is now set to `50%` and the height is set to `auto`. The images will now take up 50% of the browser window's width and adjust their height to match the original aspect ratio.

Here's just the CSS:

`.wrapper2 img {
  height: auto;
  width: 50%;
}`

Answer (score 0):

i made this code if you like.

```css
.wrapper2 img {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper2 div { float:left; width:33.33%; positive:realtive;}
```

```html
<div class ="wrapper2">
    <div>
        <a href="https://www.whitehallpubliclibrary.org/kids-parent/kids/special-events-for-kids/">
          <img src="https://www.whitehallpubliclibrary.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/kidsspecialevents.jpg">   
        </a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="https://www.whitehallpubliclibrary.org/teens-parent/teens/special-events-for-teens/">
          <img src="https://www.whitehallpubliclibrary.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/teenspecialevents.jpg">  
        </a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="https://www.whitehallpubliclibrary.org/adults-parent/adults/special-events-for-adults/">
          <img src="https://www.whitehallpubliclibrary.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/adultspecialevents.jpg">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please try this -

```
<div class ="wrapper2">
  <div>
    <a href="https://www.whitehallpubliclibrary.org/kids-parent/kids/special-events-for-kids/"><img src="https://www.whitehallpubliclibrary.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/kidsspecialevents.jpg" /></a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="https://www.whitehallpubliclibrary.org/teens-parent/teens/special-events-for-teens/"><img src="https://www.whitehallpubliclibrary.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/teenspecialevents.jpg" /></a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="https://www.whitehallpubliclibrary.org/adults-parent/adults/special-events-for-adults/"><img src="https://www.whitehallpubliclibrary.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/adultspecialevents.jpg" /></a>
  </div>
</div>

.wrapper2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
}
.wrapper2 div {
  width: calc(100%/3 - 2%);
  margin: 0 1%;
}
.wrapper2 div a, .wrapper2 div img {
  width: 100%;
}
```